# Contador parametros

Tags: python

Buenas el otro día viendo una duda de una persona la resolví de una manera pero creo que puede ser un poco rebuscada y quería proponerla aquí para ver si alguien podría hacerlo un poco más sencillo.
Hay que hacer una función en la que se dan 2 argumentos y tenemos que ver cuántas veces se repite el primer argumento en el segundo, por ejemplo si la función de llama:

```
def contador_argumento(34,234734):
```

La salida sería: 2. Ya que 34 se repite 2 veces. En fin los argumentos pueden venir como enteros o como string y como en mi solución voy a iterar con strings pues lo paso todo a string y listo, luego sustituyó el primero que esté en el segundo por cadena vacía y la diferencia del la longitud del segundo antes de sustituir con el segundo lo divido entero por la longitud del primero y viola tengo el número de repeticiones que es el mismo que la división entera sin resto de los dos.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
def contar_apariciones(a,b):
  a=str(a)#convertimos a string por si los argumentos son enteros
  b=str(b)
  large=len(a)#longitud de a
  large2=len(b)#longitud de b
  if a in str(b):
    b=re.sub(a,'',b)#mediante re.sub reemplazamos todas las veces que a está en b
  print((large2-len(b))//large)
```

#la diferencia de b antes de que sea reeplazado y despues dividido entre la longitud de a me sale las veces que se ha sustituido onlonque es = las veces

Answer (score 2):

Tan solo utiliza el método `count` de los string, esto devuelve el número de veces que se repite una cadena en otra. Para tu código sería asi:

```py
def contador_argumento(a, b):
    a = str(a)
    b = str(b)

    return b.count(a)
```

Claramente estos puede simplificar si en vez de pasar un número directamente pasas un string

```py
def contador_argumento(a, b):
    return b.count(a)
```

Y lo usas asi:

```py
contador_argumento("34","234734")
```

Comment: Pues...si jajajajaja con las vueltas que le he dado y hace tiempo utilice count. Madre mía!!!! Ok gracias

Comment: De nada, obviamente tu solución es muy larga, siempre esta bueno buscar algo simplificado y en python siempre la hay